# Error: the string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#-4.0

This is my code:

```
//Session["Date"]=ddlDate.SelectedItem+ ddlMonth.SelectedItem+ddlYear.SelectedItem;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
string date = Convert.ToString(ddlYear.SelectedItem.Value) + "/" + Convert.ToString(ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Value) + "/" + Convert.ToString(ddlDate.SelectedItem.Value);
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
// ddlYear.SelectedValue + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedValue + "/" + ddlDate.SelectedValue
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into OnlineBookingEvent(BookingEvent,BookeventDate,cdt,udt)values
                                (@BookingEvent,@BookeventDate,@cdt,@udt)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingEvent", ddlEventName.DataValueField);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookeventDate",dt);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cdt", System.DateTime.Now);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@udt", System.DateTime.Now);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

What culture are you using? If it's date-separator is not `/` the date parsing will fail since `/` is replaced with the actual date separator of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

If you want to enforce this separator you can pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as paramater for [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string date = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}"
    , ddlYear.SelectedItem.Value
    , ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Value
    , ddlDate.SelectedItem.Value); 
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

Note that `Convert.ToString(ddlYear.SelectedItem.Value)` is not needed since this property is already a string. I've also replaced your string concatenation with `String.Format` for readability reasons.

Comment: This is not working, I'm getting  an error.Error like......"The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

Comment: Could you please provide sample data? I have no psychic abilities. What values do your `DropDownList`s contain? It works if the resulting string is `2013/11/30` (for instance).

Comment: I have three dropdownlists, one is for date,second one is for month and last one is year.If we select date from the ddls it has to store in eventdate column in my database.

Comment: Yes i know, but you haven't provided any informations about the content of your dropdownlists. Repeating my last comment:  What values do your DropDownLists contain? So does the month-ddl contain "08", "8" or even "August", does the year contain "2008", "08", "8" or whatever?

Comment: DropDownList Contains 1,2,3... Months also in numeric type like 1,2,3 and year contains 2013,2014...like

Comment: Have you used the debugger since your sample data works with the code above. `DateTime.Parse("2013/11/11", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. What is the value of  `date` before `DateTime.Parse`?